# VS2012EXPRESS Ado.Net SQLite missing DLL issue

Tags: c#, sqlite, exception, ado.net

I'm trying to work out how to use ADO.Net Sqlite in VS2012 Express with no luck.

Things im doing from begining:

1. Starting new project and installing "System.Data.SQLite (x86/x64)" via NuGet for solution.
2. Adding `using System.Data.SQLite;` to directives.
3. Writing simple code like:

   SQLiteConnection sql_sck = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=test.sqlite;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");

Everything seems to look okay, VS recognize class names and changes their colors. However after running the program, in the sql_sck... line, exception is raised - about missing dll ?

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll
Additional information: Could not load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': Could not find specified module. (Exception HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Any ideas how can I make this work ? Is there anything I've done wrong / any steps missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere Visual Studio will have created SQLite.Interop.DLL. You need to find that DLL and copy it to the same directory as your application's executable.

I usually add Interop DLLs to my project as a reference and flag them for copying to the output directory in order to ensure that others that use the projects don't forget the manual step.

Comment: Done. And working. VS was putting interops into separated sub-folders in app working directory. So i guess i just have to copy exact dll for each architecture. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah -- that's we have to do -- we have subdirectories for X86 and X64